# How to set header x-api-key using HttpInterceptor in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to set the header key and value using HttpInterceptor however, I'm getting this error:

> Failed to load
>   https://example.com/api/agency:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class AddHeaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // Clone the request to add the new header.
    const authReq = req.clone({headers: req.headers.set('x-api-key', 'MY_TOKEN_VALUE')});
    // Pass on the cloned request instead of the original request.
    return next.handle(authReq);
  }
}
```

The header key is `x-api-key`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API was hosted on Amazon AWS so I had to setup proxy which fixed the issue.